# Can you tell me how can i execute last three lines in selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation

In this program I need to write a script to automate the Ecommerce site.
Main activity which is need to automate is like...
1 get URL "this is successfully executed"
2 add item to cart "this is successfully executed"
3 click on cart icon and proceed to checkout. "this is unsuccessfully executed"

for 3 point, my code is not performed. I don't know why?. I think my script is write but placement is wrong. Pls help me to find it. Thanks

> ```
> package siteTesting;
>
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
>
> import org.openqa.selenium.By;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
>
> public class ItemsAddtoCart {
>
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
> String[] itemNeeded = {"Brocolli","Cauliflower","Cucumber"};
> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Software\\geckodriver.exe");
> WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
> driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
> List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.className("product-name"));
> int noOfProduct = products.size();
> System.out.println(noOfProduct);
> int i;
> for(i=0; i<=noOfProduct; i++)
> {
> String[] NameofProduct = products.get(i).getText().split("-");
> String uNameofProduct = NameofProduct[0].trim();
> List itemNeededList = Arrays.asList(itemNeeded);
> if(itemNeededList .contains(uNameofProduct))
>
> {
> System.out.println(uNameofProduct);
> driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-action']")).get(i).click();
> }
>
> }
> 'these following lines are not executing, can you tell me why?'
> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='cart-icon']/img")).click();
> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'PROCEED TO CHECKOUT']")).click();
> driver.findElement(By.className("promoCode")).sendKeys("rahulshettyacademy");
> }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution with `WebDriverWait`  :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 15);


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='cart-icon']//img[contains(@class,'')]"))).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'PROCEED TO CHECKOUT')]"))).click();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter promo code']"))).sendKeys("PramoCode");
```

Note: please add below imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

**Working solution**

```
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.className("product-name"));
        int noOfProduct = products.size();
        System.out.println(noOfProduct);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<=itemNeeded.length; i++)
        {
            String[] NameofProduct = products.get(i).getText().split("-");
            String uNameofProduct = NameofProduct[0].trim();
            List itemNeededList = Arrays.asList(itemNeeded);
            if(itemNeededList .contains(uNameofProduct))

            {
                System.out.println(uNameofProduct);
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-action']")).get(i).click();
            }

        }



        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='cart-icon']//img[contains(@class,'')]"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'PROCEED TO CHECKOUT')]"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter promo code']"))).sendKeys("PramoCode");
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this solution is not solve the problem. after add this solution into my code i found error given below:                                                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 32, Size: 32
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at siteTesting.ItemsAddtoCart.main(ItemsAddtoCart.java:29)

Comment: ok so its not because of my code its due to your code and you are trying to iterate through wrong loop